# Does Spice have nutritional value to humans?

Tags: dune

Even if perhaps one would develop vitamin deficiencies, etc. if one ate only Spice for a long period, would Spice be something that one could eat which would prevent starvation and provide calories that would allow one to survive a long trek through the desert?

Comment: Clearly it does because sandplankton eat it aa their main source of sustenance

Comment: @Valorum: I meant to humans.

Comment: Title does not match actual question. "X has nutritional value" is not the same as "you can live on X alone".

Answer (score 4):

**[Norma Cenva](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Norma_Cenva/XD#Reborn_life_.28174-108_BG.29) *survived* on it exclusively.** (Expanded Dune universe).

It is not stated if the spice contained calories, vitamins or anything else normally regarded as necessary for survival of people, but:

> Her crews constructed an airtight clearplaz chamber where she would
> breathe gas form melange, without food and water.

Over time she changed. It's not clear if she could have been said to have survived in any traditional sense however:

> While remaining sealed in her spice chamber, her body continued to
> transform, even to the extent that her body no longer existed and she
> remained nothing less than a disembodied consciousness in a clearplaz
> globe. This consciousness came to be known as the Oracle of Infinity.

Comment: Guild Navigators also seem to survive on it